# What is the nonlinear estimator for Gaussian Random variable?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, parameter-estimation

I know that the best estimator is $g(x)=E\{Y|X=x\}$ and the conditional density for jointly Gaussian random variables is known to be Gaussian with mean and variance given by

\begin{equation}
\eta_{Y|x} = \eta_{y} + \frac{\rho_{xy} \sigma_{y}( x - \eta_{y} )}{ \sigma_{x} }
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
\sigma_{Y|x}^{2} = \sigma_{Y}^{2} ( 1 - \rho_{XY}^{2} )
\end{equation}

I am not sure how I can get that the optimal g(x) for this Gaussian case the conditional is the conditional mean:

\begin{equation}
g(x) = \eta_{x} + \frac{ \rho_{xy} \sigma_{y} (x - \eta_{y}) }{ \sigma_{x} }. 
\end{equation}

Comment: What is the question?  You know that the best estimator is $E[Y|X=x]$, that is, the mean of the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$.  You know that conditional distribution is Gaussian and you wrote down its mean $\eta_{Y|x}$.  What more do you need?

Comment: I haven´t been able to get that expression for g(x) because it is not $\eta_{Y|x}$ but it isn´t $\eta_{X|y}$ and the expression for that conditional expected value is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty yf_y(y|x)$, I don´t know how that expression is gotten

Comment: Excellent question! Anyone better here?